# ActiveMQ - difference between topic and concurrent consumer in a queue?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jms-topic

I am trying my hands on apache ActiveMQ i have made my first application using spring.i am now trying to implementing publisher/subscriber application where all the peers can take participate in publishing at any time and the subscribers will recieve whatever is published. while Googling, have came across the terms `Topic` and `the Concurrent consumers of the queue`, now i am bit confused. i have few questions regarding it :

1. How they both are different ?
2. Which could the purpose here more efficiently ?

Answer (score 3):

Concurrent consumers on a **queue** compete for messages in the queue. Exactly one consumer receives each message. Concurrent consumers in a container are usually used to improve performance, as long as message order is not important.

`Competing Consumers` is when more than one consumer competes for messages in a queue. This could be multiple containers or multiple concurrent consumers within a single container.

Consumers on a **topic** all receive each message (as long as currently subscribed, or the subscription is durable - which is **not** the default).

When listening to a topic, you would usually only have one consumer per container.